# How do I select the right element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am connecting this javascript to server code, but I am having trouble selecting the right element.  Regardless of what button I select, the video_id always ends up being the first one (in this case "bbc").  How do I change the javascript/jquery to select the right value for video_id depending on the button selected?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".removebutton").submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url:"/munch_video/",
                 data: {
                        'video_id': $('#video_id').val(), // from form
                        'playlist': $('.playlist').val(), // from form
                        'add_remove': $('.add_remove').val(), // from form 
                        },
                 success: function(message){                         
                        alert(message);
                        $('.span8').html(message);
                    }
            });
            return false;
       });

    });
</script>


        <form method='post' action = '/munch_video/ ' class = 'removebutton'>{% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" value="Channel" class = "playlist"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="bbc" id = "video_id"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="remove_video" class = "add_remove"/>

            <input type='submit' class="btn btn-danger" value='Remove from plate'/>
        </form>

        <form method='post' action = '/munch_video/ ' class = 'removebutton'>{% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" value="Channel" class = "playlist"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="toyota" id = "video_id"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="remove_video" class = "add_remove"/>

            <input type='submit' class="btn btn-danger" value='Remove from plate'/>
        </form>

        <form method='post' action = '/munch_video/ ' class = 'removebutton'>{% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" value="Channel" class = "playlist"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="gm" id = "video_id"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="remove_video" class = "add_remove"/>

            <input type='submit' class="btn btn-danger" value='Remove from plate'/>
        </form>

        can be multiple buttons, each with a different video_id value
```

Comment: ID's must be unique. This will not work.

Comment: I changed the video_id to class instead of id in my code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selector `$('#video_id')` gives you collection matching the selector but using val() on it always `applied` to `first` element. You can pass `this` as [**context with selector**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) to get `video_id` with in `descendants` of the current form.

Change

```
$('#video_id').val()
```

To

```
$('#video_id', this).val()
```

or use [**find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to search the id in descendants

```
$(this).find('#video_id').val();
```

Edit to remove the clicked form in succcess

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".removebutton").submit(function(event){
   currentForm = $(this);
   event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"/munch_video/",
             data: {
                    'video_id': $('#video_id').val(), // from form
                    'playlist': $('.playlist').val(), // from form
                    'add_remove': $('.add_remove').val(), // from form 
                    },
             success: function(message){                         
                    alert(message);
                    $('.span8').html(message);
                    currentForm.remove();
                }
        });
        return false;
   });

});
```

Comment: Great, this worked...thanks!  Another question: do you know how I would then remove the element that was selected on success.  Since the form is wrapped in div class = "span8" and because message returns the value of the video_id back again, I tried $('.span8').removeClass(message)...but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You assigned the received response to .span8 now what element you want to remove from it?

Comment: The selected button.  If I selected the "gm" button for example, I would like to remove that form/button.

Comment: I don't think I did a good job of explaining my question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716545/how-do-i-remove-an-element-class-after-success

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because you have multiple elements with the same id. Hence the same element being picked.

Since you are working on the remove button clicks, you can do a find within like

```
'video_id': $(this).find('#video_id').val()
```