# How do I remove an element class after success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When the user clicks on a button in the form associated with it's image, I'd like the image to disappear on success.  I'm having trouble implementing this.  Any advice?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".removebutton").submit(function(event){

       event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url:"/munch_video/",
                 data: {
                        'video_id': $('.video_id', this).val(), // from form
                        'playlist': $('.playlist').val(), // from form
                        'add_remove': $('.add_remove').val(), // from form 
                        },
                 success: function(message){                         
                        alert(message);
                        $('.span8').removeClass('.video_id', this);

                    }
            });
            return false;
       });

    });
</script>

<div class = "span8" style = "width: 900px;">
<!-- wrapper div -->
    <div class='wrapper huluDotCom'>

    <!-- image -->
    <div class="image" style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">

            <a href = "/partners/Business/huluDotCom">
                <img src = "/huluDotCom.png">
            </a>


        <!--  munchbutton div --> 
        <div class='munchbutton'>
            <form method='post' action = '/munch_video/ ' class = 'removebutton'><div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='dKrS8NzqPWFLM6u8wJrAeid4nGw1avGK' /></div>
                <input type="hidden" value="Channel" class = "playlist"/>
                <input type="hidden" value="huluDotCom" class = "video_id"/>
                <input type="hidden" value="remove_video" class = "add_remove"/>

                <input type='submit' class="btn btn-danger" value='Remove from plate'/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- end munchbutton div -->


    </div>
    <!-- end image div -->

    </div>
    <!-- end wrapper div -->


    <!-- wrapper div -->
    <div class='wrapper TheEllenShow'>

    <!-- image -->
    <div class="image" style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">

            <a href = "/partners/Business/TheEllenShow">
                <img src = "/TheEllenShow.png">
            </a>


        <!--  munchbutton div --> 
        <div class='munchbutton'>
            <form method='post' action = '/munch_video/ ' class = 'removebutton'><div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='dKrS8NzqPWFLM6u8wJrAeid4nGw1avGK' /></div>
                <input type="hidden" value="Channel" class = "playlist"/>
                <input type="hidden" value="TheEllenShow" class = "video_id"/>
                <input type="hidden" value="remove_video" class = "add_remove"/>

                <input type='submit' class="btn btn-danger" value='Remove from plate'/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- end munchbutton div -->


    </div>
    <!-- end image div -->

    </div>
    <!-- end wrapper div -->

</div>
```

Comment: try `$('.span8').removeClass('.video_id');`

Comment: Try $('.span8').removeClass('video_id');

Comment: where is the `.span8` in the code??

Comment: @CodeJack It's `<div class = "span8" style = "width: 900px;">`, right after the `</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your location of `event.preventDefault();` Because it will stop stop default excution.

So it should be just about the return statement.

Second you needn't have to add any other parameter for `removeClass` so it will goes like

```
$this.closest('.image').remove();
```

Where `$this` is a saved ref. if `$(this)`

Third, I could not able to find any element with class `span8` as well as `video_id` So you need to give whole code or recheck all the elements once again.

Last, also check the out the php code whether it is giving correct result or sending any error

Try this.

```
$(".removebutton").submit(function(event){
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"/munch_video/",
             data: {
                    'video_id': $('.video_id', this).val(), // from form
                    'playlist': $('.playlist').val(), // from form
                    'add_remove': $('.add_remove').val(), // from form 
                    },
             success: function(message){                         
                    alert(message);
                    $this.closest('.image').remove();

                }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
   });
```

Comment: I didn't change the preventDefault, but $this.closest('.image').remove(); worked!!  Thank you!!

Comment: Well, that was also one the possibilities. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

`$('.span8').removeClass('video_id')` no dot in the parameters of classes

Edit: As u asked for img to get removed from a div

```
$('.span8').find('img').remove()
```

to remove all images in the div,

```
$('.span8').find('img.video_id').remove()
```

to remove img's with video_id class,

if you want to just hide the element

```
$('.span8').find('.video_id').hide()
```

Comment: I tried this but the image associated with the button click doesn't get removed.

Comment: lemme know if anything mets ur requirement

Comment: Hmm I'm able to remove all the images when I do .find('img').  However the next 2 options aren't working for me.  The image stays in place.  And I don't want to remove all images with the same class.  I want to remove the image associated with the button selected.

Comment: ok..now try this...`$('.span8').find('img.video_id').remove()`

Comment: Still no luck with this last one.  Image still stays there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with your [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) call. It takes only one argument, `this` is being ignored. And the name of the class doesn't need a period in front of it.

```
//$('.span8').removeClass('.video_id', this);
$('.span8').removeClass('video_id');
```

**Edit:** It's sounds like you might need to work on your traversal. I'll assume that you have a button and an image inside of a `<div class="span8">`, something like the following

```
<div class="span8">
    <img src="cat.jpg" />
    <a href="#" class="removebutton">remove</a>
</div>
```

Then you'd need to move from your target, up to the div, and drill down the img.

```
$(this).closest('.span8').find('img').remove();
```

Comment: I tried this but the image associated with the button click doesn't get removed.

Comment: You'll need to do some traversal, judging by the html you've posted my edit should work.

Comment: I tried $(this).closest('.span8').find('img').remove(); and the image still stays there.  I put it right after alert on success and I get the success but no change to the image.

Answer (score 0):

removeClass takes only the className and no need to provide selector element inside it

```
$('.span8').removeClass('video_id');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why the image would disappear as there's nothing changing its display. How about this:

```
$('.span8').removeClass('video_id').addClass('goaway');
```

and add css `.goaway { display:none; }`

Answer (score 0):

[removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) takes the name of the class, not the selector for the class. In other words, you want to get rid of the dot.

```
$('.span8').removeClass('video_id');
```